What is the largest number that cannot be made using a multiple of $10$ and/or a multiple of $3$?
Inspired by the numberphile chicken nugget video, I was wondering: if a McDonald’s only sold $3$-packs and $10$-packs of nuggets, what is the largest number that cannot be exactly ordered? Is there an upper bound?
For example:
I could not order $8$ nuggets, $14$ nuggets, etc.
I could order $97$ nuggets, by making $1$ order of $10$ and the remaining $87$.
I can get so far as thinking: there is an upper bound (I think?!) because I can find a way to precisely order $94$, $95$ and $96$ nuggets (I could order enough tens to get multiples of $3$s, like $24$, $15$, and $6$ to fill in the rest). And once you can get $3$ in a row I feel you can make any subsequent combination.
With this logic, my hypothesis is that the upper bound is $17$. (Because I can make $18 = 6$ orders of $3$; $19 = 1$ order of $10$ and $3$ orders of $3$, $20 = 2$ orders of $10$. With a sequence of $3$ consecutive numbers, I can be “inelegant” and add a $3$-pack to continue the series forever.)
But I am at a loss on how to prove it mathematically.
This question brought to you by an inspired math-loving $9$ yr old and a non-math mom trying to fuel her kid’s passion! Thank you!

See Frobenius Coins.

Do not waste your time with numberphile-videos. They also claim without any furter explanation $1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$ , at best good for entertaining.

@Peter In my opinion, not explaining it using analytic continuation is not sufficient condition to consider watching their videos  a waste of time, it is relative matter, because they have other great videos, but I agree with you that saying the sum is $-\frac{1}{12}$ without explaining it, isn't rigorous and is misleading because it would make people mock math . What is your opinion?

I have watched many (really many) math-videos for the sake of curiousity which led actually to a waste of much time , therefore I share this experience with others so that they can avoid this mistake. You can of course have a different opinion , but I found no video helping in learning , entertaining , yes there were many hits. So it depends how you consume them. Numberphile however is unfortunately the master of clickbait , with "great sounding" titles with "nothing behind". You need of course not follow this opinion either.

However , the goal of numberphile was anyway not to publish really useful math videos , but to get fame which worked apparently perfectly considering how many innocent people became victim of their videos , in particular the $1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$ video , which got an overwhelming feedback , far far above what it deserved.

You already have all the pieces, you just need to convince yourself they constitute a proof.
You could prove 17 doesn't work by enumerating all possible quantities of 10 nugget boxes and then check whether you can get the rest with 3 nugget boxes.
You already showed that 18, 19 and 20 are all achievable. For any number bigger than 17 you can just reduce the problem by using 3 nugget boxes repeatedly until you are left with 18, 19 or 20 nuggets which can all be achieved. Hence any bigger number can be achieved as well.
As user lulu wrote in the comments, this is a well-known problem, see for example wikipedia.

Here’s a brute-force-ish approach. Consider the units place (in some sense, the only thing that matters). Every possible value is achieved by an integer less than 30:
$$0, 21, 12, 3, 24, 15, 6, 27, 18, \mbox{ and } 9 .$$
So $30$ is a trivial upper bound.
If you want a bound that’s tight, then (again brute-forcibly) you could just check the rest by inspection.
(And note the pattern in the tens place of the sequence above. You see why the pattern holds?)

Can you help me understand why 10x3 is the trivial upper bound? ie, what about its product means that every subsequent number can be derived?
(Reading the wiki also - thank you all who shared that)

Every integer $n\geq 30$ is the sum of one of those ten integers and a multiple of $10$. So, for example, each of $37, 47, 57,$ etc. is $27+10k$ for some $k$.
